# Load data in chunks from RxJs Observable from a get API, when the data is huge in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, performance, rxjs

So, I am working with an angular application where I have to fetch data (array of objects) from my backend server (spring boot) and render them as different cards in UI.

Sometimes the data from backend is so huge that the entire application will be in loading state until I receive the observable and get the data out from it.

I know I can implement some lazy loading/loading on demand from making multiple calls to backend based on page number, but my situation is I have custom pipes written in Angular that will filter all the data in UI. If I lazy render the data, the filters wont be applied to data which does not loaded yet.

I need a solution that from the observable, is there any way to get the data in chunks. So on load of first chunk of data, I will render UI and in background I can append the rest of the data to the same variable... For example: If I have 1000 data objects in an array, instead of waiting for all the 1000 objects to get loaded in a component.ts file, I wanted to load first 100, then loading screen will be gone and rest in different parts in background (100 * 10 parts)

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: This isn't really the type of question we do here (we're about fixing broken code and you don't have any...) but, yes, that's feasible. Look for paging functionality for your backend repositories. For example, if you are using `Java` and `Spring`, take a long look at the `PagingAndSortingRepository`.'

Comment: @TheHeadRush thanks for the answer. I could have used something like that, but as per my requirement, I am filtering out data based on different parameters in Angular using some custom pipes. So, if I have pagination setup, only some particular portion of data is loaded in Angular at a time, and if my filtered data is not inside it, I may get some null values on screen...

Comment: Did you read about virtual scrolling? https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm yes, my problem was not exactly the delay caused by the painting job or the rendering of huge amounts of data. Instead, the delay between I subscribe to an API and it returns data..

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the pagination in this scenario, at first get few rows, then when component A is loaded, call the api for next few rows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I could have used something like that, but as per my requirement, I am filtering out data based on different parameters in Angular using some custom pipes. So, if I have pagination setup, only some particular portion of data is loaded in Angular at a time, and if my filtered data is not inside it, I may get some null values on screen...